# Unity: animation resets scale

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, scale

my problem is I have an animator with two animations. The first animation ([1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZnDr.png) doesn't change the scale but the second ([2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpDIJ.png) does. If the first animation plays and I change the scale via code or inspector it is instantly reset to 1. This however doesn't happen if I delete the second animation out of the animator.

It seems like the animator knows there is an animation that changes the scale and therefore forbids this for everything else even though that animation isn't currently playing. Is there any way to stop that from happening.

Thanks for feedback

Comment: can you post a screenshot of animation causing issue in animation tab?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the animation inspector you have "write defaults" UNCHECKED for that specific animation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGvR6.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).